# Connecting to google's cloud SQL

Tags: sql, cloud, connect

I have been trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL as follows:

```
mysql --host=ip --user=root --password
```

I entered the password but I get an error:

```
ERROR 2003 <HY000> : Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' <10060>
```

I have no idea what to do and I am helpless. I will be glad for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your IP address to the Authorized Networks?